# How do I get a search for an int entry working in MVC EF?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to search for a 4 number postal number within MVC and the code I have doesn't work, what is stopping it from working?

So far I've tried many different solutions on the web, but none have been succesful. Not even when trying to convert it to a string, which only created a big error so I'm honestly abandoning that.

```
public ActionResult Index(int search)
        {
            var storingen = from s in db.tbl_Storing
                            select s;
            if (search != null)
            {
                storingen = storingen.Where(s => s.postcode_nr == (search));
            }
            return View(storingen.ToList());
        }
```

That is from my controller, this is from my actual view:

```
Zoek op postcode: @Html.TextBox("search")
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
```

Now when I actually fill in one of the two currently present numbers and hit search nothing happens, no error, nothing.

Comment: Have you tried setting some breakpoints and debugging?  Is the search variable actually getting properly passed in?  Check the value of storingen after you call ToList.  Also, shouldn't your search parameter be an int? (nullable), otherwise there is no need to check for null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change from `int` to `int?` and check search is null in your controller.

If user enter text like abc, search param will pass null to controller.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(int? search)
        {
            // check search null before query

            var storingen = from s in db.tbl_Storing
                            select s;
            if (search != null)
            {
                storingen = storingen.Where(s => s.postcode_nr == (search));
            }
            return View(storingen.ToList());
}
```

And this is sample for cshtml

```
 <form action="/YourController/Index" method="get">
        Zoek op postcode: @Html.TextBox("search")
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </form>
```

Comment: This doesn't work, now I get a similar error to what I got when trying to convert the int into a string "The current request for action 'Index' on controller type 'tbl_StoringController' is ambiguous between the following action methods:
System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index(System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]) on type Klantentportaal_PoC_Draft1.Controllers.tbl_StoringController
System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index() on type Klantentportaal_PoC_Draft1.Controllers.tbl_StoringController"

Comment: Did you add [HttpGet] attribule?

Comment: The error is gone now, but the part from "/YourController/Index" is causing problems. It doesn't recognise "/tbl_StoringController/Index" nor "/~Controllers/Index" resulting in a 404

Comment: I found the issue, apologies. Thanks for the assistance!